# Turbo-Rails: How can I add add a Turbo Frame to `application.html.erb`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo, turbo-rails

I ran the following in the command line:

```bash
> rails new test-turbo
> rails g controller Home index
```

Added the following route to `config/routes.rb`:

```rb
resources :home, only: [:index]
```

Wrapped the `<%= yield %>` in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` in a turbo frame tag:

```
  <body>
    <%= turbo_frame_tag :foobar do %>
      <%= yield %>
    <% end %>
  </body>
```

Added a link in `app/views/home/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to "Link to this page", home_index_path %>
```

Then, when clicking on that link, I get a turbo frame error:
[image: content missing]

If I move the turbo frame tag into the home/index page, it works fine:

`app/views/home/index.html.erb`

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag :foobar do %>
  <h1>Home#index</h1>
  <p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
  <%= link_to "Link to this page", home_index_path %>
<% end %>
```

[image: no error]

Why does this work, but putting it in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` doesn't work?  It's generating the same HTML at the end of the day, right?

In case its helpful, [here's the GitHub repo](https://github.com/a-lavis/test-turbo).  Commit `537c40a` has the error, commit `b42ca66` works fine.

Update: here's a gif displaying [a solution that works with two turbo frames, one that is persistent across pages](https://github.com/a-lavis/test-turbo/commit/5f29cf702087ef670a97586128fa0065f72b53c5):
[image: top bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When navigating in a frame your `application` layout isn't rendered. Which you can see from the logs:

```bash
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/turbo_rails/frame (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 38)
```

You're looking at the inspector and `<turbo-frame id="foobar">`, when you click the link, current page html is not replaced with the response html, that's really the whole point of a frame. Only content inside the frame is updated. You can see the actual response from the network tab:

[image]

No turbo frame in the response ^

To render your layout, you can explicitly set it in the controller to [override](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/v1.4.0/app/controllers/turbo/frames/frame_request.rb#L24) turbo frame's [layout](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/v1.4.0/app/views/layouts/turbo_rails/frame.html.erb#L1):

```
layout "application"
```

Just FYI, there is very little need for turbo frame in the layout, especially, one that wraps around everything. `<body>` element already acts like a frame, and another frame directly under it doesn't really gain you anything.

---

**Update**

Maybe having a whole controller is bit too much. I'd start with something simple. The simplest way is to always render `application` layout. Skipping layout rendering is only an optimization to speed things up, anything outside of the frame gets discarded anyway.

You can add some `if..else` to the layout:

```rb
...
<body>
  <% unless request.headers["Turbo-Frame"] == "main_content" %>
    <%= turbo_frame_tag :side_bar do %>
      # TODO: sidebar
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= turbo_frame_tag :main_content do %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @alex for the detailed answer, especially those links to the `turbo-rails` code!

What if I'm doing more in the `application` layout, for example rendering a sidebar that also uses turbo.  I want this sidebar to be on every page, but I don't want Turbo to re-render the sidebar when re-rendering the main content, and vice-versa.  What would be a good way to go about that?  See [here](https://github.com/a-lavis/test-turbo/commit/09676e4869ee88e6443f6be66d9c86d18ef1577c#diff-f43fe075643e681b2c01c2f853bb0c4299d135b47fcbd4da96890d521c49e3ebR13-R21) for an example.

Comment: Update: I found a way to do this, but I wonder if anyone knows of a better way to do it.  See the update in the main question.

Comment: @a-lavis see update. i'd say try to keep it simple, just render the `application` layout, you can optimize later and render just the part you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is adding

```rb
  layout -> { 'turbo_frame' if turbo_frame_request? }
```

to `ApplicationController` and then creating `app/views/layouts/turbo_frame.html.slim` with

```rb
= turbo_frame_tag :foobar
  = yield
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you were trying to **keep layout stuff (sidebar, footer etc.) from rerendering**, you could have used `data-turbo-permanent`.

Permanent elements persist across page loads.

Then you wouldn´t have to wrap your main content in a turbo frame.

[See documentation](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#persisting-elements-across-page-loads).